# A self contained Javascript/Html module - Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, module, include

*[EDIT: I have possibly found another solution. Kooilnc's solution looks good. Is the solution at the bottom of this question better or worse than Kooilnc's?]*

I have a `div` with associated javascript code. I would like to have the html for just this `div` and the associated javascript code all in **one** file, a kind of self contained 'module', eg

mydiv.html

```
<html>
<div id="Wibble" style="display: none;">
    ... loads of structure for just this div
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ... loads of js functions just associated with this div
</script>
</html>
```

Then in my main page `index.html` I would like to include this 'module' in some way.

The only thing I have found is a Server Side Include:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ... loads of stuff
</head>
<body>
   ... loads of other html structure

   <!--#include FILE="mydiv.html" -->

   ... loads of other html structure and script tags
</body>
</html>
```

**Question 1: Is there a better way of doing this?**

**Question 2: Should I have the html tag in mydiv.html as that will obviously put an html tag in index.html which is out of place?**

**Question 3: If that html tag in Q2 should not be there, how do I write the mydiv.html file so it has all the formatting and nice coloured structure in Visual Studio Code?**

---

**Edit:**

Kooilnc's solution (below in the answers) looks good. Here is another solution I have found. It is working in my development environment Visual Studio Code. I need the javascript in my included html file in `body`'s `onload`. Does anyone know if this solution will work on a server with my `body` `onload` requirement? Is it better or worse than Kooilnc's solution?

Jquery must be included with the normal `<script>` tag prior to this.

I insert this code within index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ... loads of stuff
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">  
</head>
<body>
   ... loads of other html structure

   <div id="include_mydiv"></div>
   <script>
       $(function(){
           $("#include_mydiv").load("mydiv.html");
       });
   </script>

   ... loads of other html structure and script tags
</body>
</html>
```

And mydiv.html did not have any `<html>` tags:

```
<div id="Wibble" style="display: none;">
    ... loads of structure for just this div
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ... loads of js functions just associated with this div
</script>
```

Comment: you may try [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

Comment: Check [templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots)

Comment: Hi @Kooilnc, are you saying in my `mydiv.html` I should replace my `<html>` tag with `<template>` and then have the `<script>` tag as normal?

Comment: Hi @Rewind see my answer for an idea. Not sure it's the *right* idea, but still ... an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try importing from [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement) elements. Here is a simplified templating example that may be useful.

If you need to import from an external file, check [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zutxnw?file=index.js) I cooked up for you.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`[data-import]`).forEach( el => {
  if (!el.dataset.imported) {
    el.appendChild(document.querySelector(`#${el.dataset.import}`)
      .content.cloneNode(true));
    el.dataset.imported = `ok`;
  }
});
```

```html
<template id="someForm">
    <script>
      document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
      function handle(evt) {
        if (evt.target.nodeName === `BUTTON`) {
          alert(`Yes. I am handled`);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <button id="sub">Handle me!</button>
</template>

<template id="somethingElse">
    <style type="text/css">
      .red {color: red;}
    </style>
    <p class="red">I am appended too</p>
</template>

<div data-import="someForm"></div>
<div data-import="somethingElse"></div>
```

Comment: This looks good @Kooilnc . I have found another solution involving jQuery. It seems to work. Which would be considered better and why?

Comment: @Rewind how can we decide which is better between this and an unknown other solution?

Comment: Sorry @VLAZ, it took me longer to update my question. It is done now.

Comment: @Rewind it's not so much what's *better*, it's what works best for you. I suppose jQuery can make things easier, but you may have to check if the javascript is of `mydiv.html` works as expected etc.

Comment: How is it better than creating and loading an iframe onclick?

Comment: @PetrL. One thing that springs to mind is that iframes can't (implicitly) use the scripting or styling of their parent.

Answer (score -2):

Use an Iframe

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="mydiv.html">
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: OP said Include the HTML file, `iframe` makes a new document with the content of `mydiv.html`

Comment: @PyxlDavon You're splitting hairs here. He wants to use a webpage in a different webpage. He's doing pretty much the same thing but server side and with slightly different resulting html tags. After all it is including the file to the end user. So present your own better solution, dear critic.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Petr L, but PyxlDavon is right. I want my mydiv.html to actually be part of index.html, not as an iframe. I want javascript contained in index.html to actually set the display of the Wibble div to block from none.